# RaspberryPI: Making SIP outbound calls using linphonec or an alternative SIP soft phone

Tags: raspberry-pi, sip, telephony, linphone

In my project I want my Raspberry PI to dial an outbound PSTN number.

I have a SIP account with an assigned regular phone number and I can make the mentioned outbound calls on OSX using [Telephone.app](http://www.tlphn.com):

[image: call-ok]

Now I tried to achieve the same on my raspberry PI using `linphonec`

First I register my SIP Provider with linphone with seems to succeed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linphone
$ linphonec

linphonec> register sip:4100000004@free4.voipgateway.org free4.voipgateway.org <PASSWORD>

Registration on sip:free4.voipgateway.org successful.
```

Then I attempt to call `004100000018` with results in an error.

```
linphonec> call 0041000000018

Establishing call id to <sip:0041000000018@free4.voipgateway.org>, assigned id 1
Contacting <sip:0041000000018@free4.voipgateway.org>
Call 1 to <sip:0041000000018@free4.voipgateway.org> in progress.
Remote ringing.
Early media.
Call 1 with <sip:0041000000018@free4.voipgateway.org> early media.
Call declined.
Call 1 with <sip:0041000000018@free4.voipgateway.org> ended (Call declined).
```

I also tried `+41` rather than `0041` but this did not work either. 
The PI is connected to the internet but I am not sure if this is some Proxy or firewall problem or if I am not using linphone properly.

**Note:**
Generally I don't necessarily have to use linphone. So if there is another non-UI sip client that would do the job and that I could somehow tap into using scripts or an API then I would be more than happy to do that too.

#### Troubleshooting

I did bring up the log level and encountered:

```
ortp-error-eXosip_dnsutils_naptr_lookup: res_query failed ('free4.voipgateway.org NAPTR')
```

I then found the following remark on this [thread](http://nongnu.13855.n7.nabble.com/Problem-with-Proxy-since-version-3-2-td171156.html)

> Your version of exosip may be old and buggy. 
>   You may try to update exosip and recompile your version of linphone. 
>   Or better, clone linphone from git and new sip stack belle-sip.

So I checked the version of linphonec and I currently got 3.5.2 while on the website they advertise 3.8. So I will attempt to upgrade to version 3.7 using <del>this [guide](http://sagar.se/linphone-3.7.0-wheezy.html).</del> this [guide](http://akh1.blogspot.ch/2014/04/compiling-linphone-37-in-ubuntu.html)

**Update**:

Similar questions on SO:

- [Installing the "ring.cx SIP client" on a Raspberry PI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714733/installing-the-ring-cx-sip-client-on-a-raspberry-pi)
- [SIP-Client for Raspberry Pi that works from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435648/sip-client-for-raspberry-pi-that-works-from-command-line/29715067#29715067)

Comment: The NAPTR failure is not related. The SIP standard  -[Locating SIP Servers](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3263.txt)- requires to find the server using NAPTR. When it fails, eXosip2 will do a simple DNS lookup. In practice, you just loose a few milliseconds for the NAPTR. This only means your service is not fully compliant as it should have NAPTR defined.

Answer (score 2):

I am also working with raspberry pi's and VoIP and also tried out linphone. I had many troubles and switched to [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org), which is way better. It has a good documentation and much more functionalitys.

The problem it the setup, because you have to install it by source. I installed it on raspbian jessy like this (run as root or use sudo):

```
apt−get install build−essential automake autoconf libtool libasound2−dev libpulse−dev libssl−dev libsamplerate0−dev libcommoncpp2−dev libccrtp −dev libzrtpcpp −dev libdbus −1−dev libdbus −c++−dev libyaml −dev libpcre3 −dev libgsm1−dev libspeex−dev libspeexdsp−dev libcelt −dev
cd /home/pi
wget http://www.pjsip.org/release/2.4.5/pjproject −2.4.5.tar.bz2 tar −xvjf pjproject −2.4.5.tar.bz2
cd pjproject −2.4.5.tar.bz2
./configure && make dep && make
```

Important to say that this is the minimal installation, for video support or more codecs you should visit this [getting started guide](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Autoconf).

If your problem is really the firewall all this won't help you. What i did is setup my own VoIP-Server called [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org). It takes some afford and time but afterwards you will have a nice system which does not depends on online-services. Another solution would be to configure your router right, so he bypasses the calls from free4.voipgateway.org to your raspberry.