# Installing the "ring.cx SIP client" on a Raspberry PI

Tags: python, c++, raspberry-pi, sip, headless

### The Situation

I would like to get terminal-based (headless) SIP calls working on my Raspberry Pi and I already tried this using linphone:

[RaspberryPI: Making SIP outbound calls using linphonec or an alternative SIP soft phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637142/raspberrypi-making-sip-outbound-calls-using-linphonec-or-an-alternative-sip-sof)

Since I am currently stuck there I wanted to try another option which was  [SFLPhone](http://sflphone.org). They pointed me towards the [ring](http://ring.cx) software project which offers a daemon `dring` which allows making SIP calls using a scripting interface:

> Indeed, the daemon can run standalone and be controlled using the DBus API.
>
> Note the project have been renamed to "Ring" (version is bumped to 2.x). Experimental packages are available at http://ring.cx/en/documentation/linux-installation 
>   A major feature of Ring 
>   2.x is the optional "DHT" account type allowing to make calls without any SIP server.
>   There are many other enhancements such as ICE support, UPnP support, stability improvements etc.
>   (note clients are being re-written (GTK3, Qt5) and there is a new OS X client, they are not yet feature complete and in heavy development.)
>
> The new daemon `dring` source Git repo URI is : https://gerrit-ring.savoirfairelinux.com/ring .
>   The DBus API is mostly the same as before. In the `tools/dringctrl` directory you will find an example python client that we use for testing (uses `python3-dbus`).
>
> We are willing to fix any bugs you may find, the daemon bugtracker is here : https://projects.savoirfairelinux.com/projects/ring-daemon/issues
>   Also look at https://projects.savoirfairelinux.com/projects/ring/wiki for build instruction etc.
>
> Regards and good luck for your embedded project,
>   A. B.

### Compiling the dependencies

I tried to compile the dependencies for the project like stated in the `README`:

```
git clone https://gerrit-ring.savoirfairelinux.com/ring
cd ring
```

Compile the dependencies first

```
cd ../contrib/
rm -fr native/ && mkdir native
cd native
../bootstrap
make
```

I got this error:

```
libvpx.webm-4640a0c4804b/third_party/googletest/src/include/gtest/gtest.h
mv libvpx-4640a0c4804b49f1870d5a2d17df0c7d0a77af2f libvpx && touch libvpx
cd libvpx && CROSS= ./configure --target=armv7-linux-gcc \
    --as=yasm --disable-docs --disable-examples --disable-unit-tests --disable-install-bins --disable-install-docs --enable-realtime-only --enable-error-concealment --disable-runtime-cpu-detect --disable-webm-io --enable-pic --prefix=/home/pi/ring/contrib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  disabling docs
  disabling examples
  disabling unit_tests
  disabling install_bins
  disabling install_docs
  enabling realtime_only
  enabling error_concealment
  disabling runtime_cpu_detect
  disabling webm_io
  enabling pic
Configuring selected codecs
  enabling vp8_encoder
  enabling vp8_decoder
  enabling vp9_encoder
  enabling vp9_decoder
Configuring for target 'armv7-linux-gcc'
  enabling armv7
  enabling neon
  enabling neon_asm
  enabling media
Unable to invoke compiler: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64

Configuration failed. This could reflect a misconfiguration of your
toolchains, improper options selected, or another problem. If you
don't see any useful error messages above, the next step is to look
at the configure error log file (config.log) to determine what
configure was trying to do when it died.
../../contrib/src/vpx/rules.mak:105: recipe for target '.vpx' failed
make: *** [.vpx] Error 1
```

### Compiling ring

Despite compiling the dependencies failed I did attempt to compile ring:

```
git clone https://gerrit-ring.savoirfairelinux.com/ring
cd ring
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

This caused the following error:

```
checking for PJPROJECT... no
configure: error: Missing pjproject files
pi@phone ~/ring $     make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
pi@phone ~/ring $     make install
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

So currently I am stuck and I fear that I will not be able to go beyond  [the current state of my project](http://vimeo.com/gurgeli/dial-phone) ():

[image: the-phone]

**Edit**: Now without the video codecs (like aberaud suggested) I run into the following error:

```
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../include/opendht -I/home/pi/sip-desaster/ring/contrib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include -fPIC -I/home/pi/sip-desaster/ring/contrib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include  -g -fPIC -O3 -std=c++0x -I/home/pi/sip-desaster/ring/contrib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include  -g -fPIC -O3 -std=c++0x -c -o libopendht_la-dht.lo `test -f 'dht.cpp' || echo './'`dht.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../include/opendht -I/home/pi/sip-desaster/ring/contrib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include -fPIC -I/home/pi/sip-desaster/ring/contrib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include -g -fPIC -O3 -std=c++0x -I/home/pi/sip-desaster/ring/contrib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include -g -fPIC -O3 -std=c++0x -c dht.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o libopendht_la-dht.o
In file included from ../include/opendht/dht.h:29:0,
                 from dht.cpp:27:
../include/opendht/infohash.h:58:22: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
dht.cpp:3105:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
Makefile:386: recipe for target 'libopendht_la-dht.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [libopendht_la-dht.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/sip-desaster/ring/contrib/native/opendht/src'
Makefile:395: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/sip-desaster/ring/contrib/native/opendht'
../../contrib/src/opendht/rules.mak:28: recipe for target '.opendht' failed
make: *** [.opendht] Error 2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435648/sip-client-for-raspberry-pi-that-works-from-command-line/29715067

Comment: So do you have your crosscompiller installed? What `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v` prints?

Comment: this does not seem to be available `-bash: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found`. I don't know if this is a dependency which will be created when building the `contrib` stuff...

Comment: No it's on a raspberry pi with raspbian

Comment: You compile your lib on raspberry itself? Then why do you configure with `--target=armv7-linux-gcc`? This options assumes crosscompiling

Comment: I did not set this target myself. This is a library which I am not the author of and I am also not a C expert at all. However, I fear that I might turn into one, trying to install this library :-)

Comment: Do you at least have your c compiler installed? Does `gcc -v` work? Your library is configured to be crossocompiled from x86 to arm for now.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Contrib

The "contrib" part of the Ring build is about building dependencies that are not available on the target system, mostly used to build full working packages when cross-compiling or for systems without proper dependency management (basically all OSs except Linux distros).

When in the `contrib/native` directory, you can run `make list` to see the list of packages to be built. Since you are cross-compiling you will need to build almost everything.

If you somehow mess up the contrib build you can safely delete the `contrib/native` and `contrib/{target_tuple}` (if any) directories and start again.

### libvpx

The libvpx library is used by libav to provide the vp8 and vp9 video codecs. It's not an hard dependency and since your project doesn't use video you can safely disable it. We also encountered issues when cross compiling vpx.

In `contrib/src/libav/rules.mak` line 70, `DEPS_libav` defines the list of dependencies for libav. You can remove `vpx`, `x264` and `$(DEPS_vpx)` from the list since you don't use video. You may also add speex and opus audio codecs to the list (they should be in the list but aren't, see [this patch](https://gerrit-sflphone.savoirfairelinux.com/#/c/1624/9/contrib/src/libav/rules.mak) 
as an example).

After cleaning contrib as described above and boostraping again, when running `make list`, `vpx` and `x264` shouldn't show up in the list of "To-be-built packages". Then try to build contrib by running `make`.

If after trying this you encounter the same issue for other packages you may have some sort of cross compilation build path issue (I would then need more logs/details).

As a very last resort, compiling on the Pi itself (with Raspbian) is horribly slow but has the advantage to [use local distro-provided dependencies](https://projects.savoirfairelinux.com/projects/ring-daemon/wiki/Debian-based) and remove the hassles of cross compilation.

Good luck

Comment: In a first version I was referring to contrib/build, it's the same as contrib/native (the directory name doesn't matter)

Comment: I tried your approach but it still fails after 169 minutes of compiling... See my updated answer below.

Comment: Note the VPX issue should now be fixed in master

Answer (score 1):

I am providing an own answer which should document my steps which will hopefully lead me to the desired end result:

#### Download the sources

```
git clone https://gerrit-ring.savoirfairelinux.com/ring
cd ring
```

#### Build the `contrib` section

According to [@aberaud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641095/aberaud)'s [remarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29722221/784318) I can update `contrib/src/libav/rules.mak` and remove any video-related dependencies (remember that I am headless):

So I changed line 70 form

```
DEPS_libav = zlib x264 vpx $(DEPS_vpx)
```

to

```
DEPS_libav = zlib opus speex
```

Now build the `contrib` section.

```
cd ../contrib/
rm -fr native/ && mkdir native
cd native
../bootstrap
make
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting the same error trying to compile the contrib.

The version of Raspbian I was using came with the older version of the gcc compiler, version 4.6.  After I upgraded to 4.8 it compiled instantly. Well, as instantly as anything compiles on the Pi at any rate.